# Docker container with Neo4j 2.3 enterprise edition exits without error message when mounting graph.db volume

Tags: docker, neo4j

I have a snapshot of a graph.db that is over 40 gb in size. That snapshot came from a server running Neo4j 2.2.8. Now I'm trying to run this database locally to explore the existing graph without wasting resources and potentially crashing the server.

To do so, I'm using Neo4j via Docker and mounting that snapshot. At least that's what I'm trying to do via `docker run -p 7474:7474 --ulimit=nofile=40000:40000 --env=NEO4J_CACHE_MEMORY=8G --env=NEO4J_ALLOW_STORE_UPGRADE=true --env=NEO4J_AUTH=none --volume=$HOME/graph.db:/data/graph.db neo4j:enterprise`

*This docker image uses the enterprise edition of Neo4j 2.3.2 and therefore needs to set allow_store_upgrade to true.*

The only output I'm getting is this:

`Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
2016-03-02 22:43:44.277+0000 INFO  No SSL certificate found, generating a self-signed certificate..
2016-03-02 22:43:45.718+0000 INFO  Initiating metrics..`

Then the container stops and I get control back of the command line.
`docker ps -l` shows that the container exits with status code **137**.

My question here is: How can I troubleshoot this (non-)error and run this dataset on my local machine in a safe environment?

---

Now when I start Neo4j 2.3.2 community edition on localhost with $HOME/graph.db as the database path, the store gets updated and after a short while, Neo4j is accessible.

With the upgraded store in place, I stopped Neo4j on localhost and tried to re-run docker on the upgraded database.

This is the (logged) output:

`Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
2016-03-07 17:14:17.835+0000 INFO  No SSL certificate found, generating a self-signed certificate..
2016-03-07 17:14:19.214+0000 INFO  Initiating metrics..
2016-03-07 17:15:05.068+0000 INFO  Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server
2016-03-07 17:15:05.070+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@13ae26d2' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@13ae26d2' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@13ae26d2' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:67)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:234)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:97)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.start(CommunityBootstrapper.java:48)
    at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseBootstrapper.main(EnterpriseBootstrapper.java:32)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@13ae26d2' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:462)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:194)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.enterprise.EnterpriseFacadeFactory, /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.enterprise.EnterpriseFacadeFactory.newFacade(EnterpriseFacadeFactory.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.EnterpriseGraphDatabase.<init>(EnterpriseGraphDatabase.java:57)
    at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseNeoServer$2.newGraphDatabase(EnterpriseNeoServer.java:67)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:95)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexingService@7d237704' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:434)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:66)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:102)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:600)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:112)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:139)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TermBuffer.toTerm(TermBuffer.java:122)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentTermEnum.term(SegmentTermEnum.java:184)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TermInfosReaderIndex.<init>(TermInfosReaderIndex.java:77)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TermInfosReader.<init>(TermInfosReader.java:116)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.<init>(SegmentCoreReaders.java:83)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.get(SegmentReader.java:116)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.get(SegmentReader.java:94)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.<init>(DirectoryReader.java:105)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlyDirectoryReader.<init>(ReadOnlyDirectoryReader.java:27)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader$1.doBody(DirectoryReader.java:78)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:709)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:72)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.open(IndexReader.java:256)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneIndexWriter.isOnline(LuceneIndexWriter.java:74)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneSchemaIndexProvider.getInitialState(LuceneSchemaIndexProvider.java:119)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexingService.init(IndexingService.java:225)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:424)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:66)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:102)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:600)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:112)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:139)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.enterprise.EnterpriseFacadeFactory.newFacade(EnterpriseFacadeFactory.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.EnterpriseGraphDatabase.<init>(EnterpriseGraphDatabase.java:57)
    at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseNeoServer$2.newGraphDatabase(EnterpriseNeoServer.java:67)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:95)`

Comment: it works nicely with a local installation of 2.3.2-community (via homebrew)... the question is: Why not docker?

Comment: any further insights with `docker logs <containername>` ?

Comment: No, `docker logs <containername>` has the same output as above.

Comment: There is however an error when I upgrade the db via localhost and then re-run docker. Description and error in the original post added.